# List get empty for every rerender on jsp page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, renderer

I am new to using JSP, I have used JSF much before but now need to build a portlet with JSP.

I put a string in my list in my java code every time the user presses the submit button. But each time the list is cleared and only have the size of 1 and i dont know why. I guess I get a new instance of Main each time the page rerender.

How do I fix this?

My JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:useBean id="Main" class="com.classes.Main" /> 

<div>

   La Till:  <%= request.getParameter("inputText")%>
   <form name="myForm" action="" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="inputText" >
      <input type="submit" value="Lägg till!">
   </form>

<%
    String name = request.getParameter("inputText");

    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
        Main.addToList(name);
    }

%>

<c:forEach var="name" items="${Main.list}">
    <tr>
    <c:out value="${name}"></c:out>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

My Java:

```
public class Main extends HttpServlet {

  private List <String> pplList = new ArrayList();

  public void addToList(String inName)
  {
      pplList.add(inName);
  }

  public List <String> getList()
  {
      return pplList;
  }


  public void setList(List <String> inList)
  {
      pplList = inList;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where to start... you seem to have a misunderstanding on how to combine servlets and JSPs, possibly because of your prior exposure to JSF. So you might want to read the [Java EE tutorial on servlets and JSPs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html) first.

Having said that, let's look at your code.

First of all, you have to understand that (conceptually) your JSP is executed in its entirety on every request. This also means that the `<jsp:useBean>` tag is evaluated on every request. This tag looks in your current request attributes for a bean called `Main`. If it does not exist, it will instantiate a new one.

So in this case, at every render, a new `Main` object is instantiated, which means that the field initializer `private List <String> pplList = new ArrayList();` is executed on every request.

This problem can be solved by using the `scope` attribute on `<jsp:useBean>` like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="Main" class="com.classes.Main" scope="session" />
```

Now the tag will look for a bean called `Main` in the *session* attributes; and will therefore return an existing `Main` instance on each subsequent request.

That answers your immediate problem.

However, your `Main` class is weird...

```
public class Main extends HttpServlet {...
```

You are using `Main` as a model (in MVC terminology), so there is no need to extend `HttpServlet`. The fact that you do, suggests that you wanted to implement a [Model 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2) servlet. Again, I refer you to the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html).

And finally, you mention that you need to build a *portlet*. Unfortunately, the Portlet API is somewhat different from the Servlet API -- getting the above code to work will *not* help you in effectively implementing a portlet.

Comment: Thanks for a really good answer! The Scope helped.
I've had a hard time finding good information about the JSP and portlets so thanks for the links. I tried the code as a portlet in the CMS tool I use and it seems to work but you say that there are better ways to build portlets on.Do you have any guides and good suggestions on how to build portlets? CMS tool uses a tomcat server and I need to use Maven. I would prefer to build the portlet in JSF. I've Googled around but not found any good way to build portlets on so feel free to give me some tips.
Again, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Hey Johan, *portlet* is unfortunately a heavily overloaded term. I was referring to the standard Java Portlet Specification, but the fact that your JSP works in your CMS makes me think that your CMS uses a different concept under the same name.